Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_netinfo:generateDebugLintReportModel'
upon executing ./gradlew build in my react-native application I am getting the Exception below.
NOTE: the application was initially fine but I am upgrading Gradle and react-native so I started getting trouble that I fixed but I am stuck at this one.
I tried the usual answers which are to clean the cache and to reinstall node_modules. I also looked into compatibility and it looks like jdk, gradle, react-native and this netInfo package seem compatible.
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_netinfo:generateDebugLintReportModel'.

Build information
 android build gradle           7.3.1
 react-native-community/netinfo   8.3.1
    Gradle        8.0.1
    react-native  0.71.4
    Kotlin:       1.8.10
    Groovy:       3.0.13
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
    JVM:          17.0.10 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
    OS:           Mac OS X 13.5 x86_64

Stacktrace:
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)

Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.BuildIdentifier.getBuildPath()'
   

with stacktrace:
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.BuildIdentifierMethods$getBuildPath$1.transform(BuildIdentifierMethods.kt:43)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.BuildIdentifierMethods$getBuildPath$1.transform(BuildIdentifierMethods.kt:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$Present.transform(ValueSupplier.java:541)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.mapValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateOwnPresentValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.ArtifactInput.computeDependencies$gradle_core(AndroidLintInputs.kt:2340)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidArtifactInput.toLintModel$gradle_core(AndroidLintInputs.kt:1939)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.VariantInputs.toLintModel(AndroidLintInputs.kt:1384)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.LintModelWriterTask.doTaskAction(LintModelWriterTask.kt:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:66)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:97)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor888.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)

opinion: even though the packages seem compatible, and i also played around with different versions and it didn't work, i still believe that this is a compatibility problem.
